# CodeBlocks how to watch dynamically allocated array c++ with debugger

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, watch

For instance i want to see the values in the debugg watch tab for the *point array just like i can see them for arry[] array. The field just shows the address and i cant right click it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int *point=new int[3]{1,2,3};
int arry[3]={4,5,6};

for(int i(0); i<3; i++)
    cout<<point[i]<<" ";

cout<<endl;
for(int i(0); i<3; i++)
    cout<<arry[i]<<" ";
}
```

[debugg watcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkdk4.png)

Comment: Technically the pointer just points to the first element in the dynamically allocate array. There's just no information about size or length. Therefore it's impossible for the debugger to show all elements. You have to add watches for them explicitly, like `point[1]` etc.

Comment: I figured as much, since its a declared as a pointer...  still had some hope that there is a way.